# Git Hub validation token and DDH does not work

Tags: github, token

I'm trying to connect remotely with GitHub and I've tried via Token validation and SSH validation. Unsuccessful in both.

I even turned off the firewall protection but to no avail.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

The follow step:

!git clone git@github.com:a15cardoso/projetos-ebac.git

Return:
Cloning into 'projetos-ebac'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

After the token was deactivated, I configured the SSH key. Hopefully the connection works and I'm able to clone the repository.